# Como retornar um JSON com caracteres especiais no Flask?

Tags: python, flask

Quando retorno um JSON através dos métodos `make_response(jsonify())`, meu navegador não consegue entender os caracteres especiais, como retornar JSON na codificação UTF-8?

Segue o código:

```
@app.route('/', methods=['GET'])
def index():
    return make_response(jsonify(address_info('Rua Parianas, 665 São Paulo').to_json()), 201)
```

Resposta que eu gostaria de receber:

```
{
  "city": "São Paulo", 
  "country": "Brazil", 
  "lat": -23.5100646, 
  "lng": -46.54488689999999, 
  "neighborhood": "Jardim Jaú (Zona Leste)", 
  "state": "SP", 
  "street_name": "Rua Parianas", 
  "street_number": "665"
}
```

Resposta que estou recebendo:

```
{
  "city": "S\u00e3o Paulo", 
  "country": "Brazil", 
  "lat": -23.5100646, 
  "lng": -46.54488689999999, 
  "neighborhood": "Jardim Ja\u00fa (Zona Leste)", 
  "state": "SP", 
  "street_name": "Rua Parianas", 
  "street_number": "665"
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A resposta do arquivo JSON está perfeitamente ok! Caracteres especiais são codificados dessa forma por questão de compatibilidade e segurança; por conta de html escaping(que pode trazer vulnerabilidades para o sistema) e code page. (Na China se utiliza BIG5, e no Japão SJIS invés de UTF-8 por exemplo..)

Quando for pegar os dados JSON é só trata-lo da forma correta, utilizando a biblioteca JSON ou codecs do Python para decodifica-lo.